# JavaScript: embedded YouTube video not playing in modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which looks at a specific css class `.vma_iFramePopup` and from it, takes the link stored in the `src`. And then loads that in a modal popup.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".vma_overlay").click(function (event) {

        var $videoSrcOriginal = $(event.target).siblings('.vma_iFramePopup').attr("src");

        // Check if the embedded youtube url has any attributes appended
        // by looking for a '?' in the url.
        // If one is found, append our autoplay attribute using '&',
        // else append it with '?'.

        if ($videoSrcOriginal.indexOf('?') > -1) {

            var $videoSrc = $videoSrcOriginal

            // when the modal is opened autoplay it
            $('#vma_ModalBox').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

                // set the video src to autoplay
                var $videoSrcAuto = $videoSrc + "&autoplay=1&mute=1";
                $("#vma_video").attr('src', $videoSrcAuto);

                $('body').addClass("modalyt");
            })

        } else {

            var $videoSrc = $(".vma_iFramePopup").attr("src");

            // when the modal is opened autoplay it
            $('#vma_ModalBox').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {

                // set the video src to autoplay
                var $videoSrcAuto = $videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&mute=1";
                $("#vma_video").attr('src', $videoSrcAuto);

                $('body').addClass("modalyt");
            })

        }

        // stop playing the youtube video when modal is closed
        $('#vma_ModalBox').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {

            $("#vma_video").attr('src', $videoSrc);

            $('body').removeClass("modalyt");
        })
    });
});
```

I was informed that the videos are not playing in the modal. The modal when loaded is empty.

When I check the browser console, I am not seeing any relevant errors.

When I check the iframe inside my modal popup I see that it says

> src(unknown)

in the src element:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="80%" height="80%" src(unknown) id="vma_video" allowfullscreen="" data-gtm-yt-inspected-9256558_25="true">></iframe>
```

I have not been able to identify why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the solution in this particular case was to replace:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

with:

```
window.onload = function () {
```

For some reason specific to our setup, the jquery way of getting document ready was not firing.

Answer (score 0):

I 've tried fiddling on the live website with a very slight variation of your code and it seems to work:

```
$('.vma_overlay').on('click', function() {

    var $videoSrcOriginal = $(this).siblings('.vma_iFramePopup').attr("src");

    if ($videoSrcOriginal.indexOf('?') > -1) {
        $('#vma_ModalBox').show();
        var $videoSrcAuto = $videoSrcOriginal + "&autoplay=1&mute=1";
        $('#vma_ModalBox #vma_video').attr('src', $videoSrcAuto);
        $('body').addClass("modalyt");
    }
});
```

Comment: Interesting, I can't get it to work with your version?

Comment: So pasting this into the console does not work for you eh?
Any error messages? Any other clue that could help?
I am getting some error messages from the console, for example FindApi is not defined

Comment: So weird, I finally got it to work by swapping out `$(document).ready(function () {` with  `window.onload = function () {` ?

Comment: Thank you anyway for your help! :-)